# Can I use github projects in my app fo commericial use?

Tags: android, github

I use some libraries like ColorPicker, I downloaded the project and used as a module in my app. Do I get any problem when the app is published to Google Play Store? The color picker is an open source public project in github and this is the one I am talking about https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker

Comment: You need to check the license of the libraries you use. Here it is for ColorPicker: https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Can someone tell why this question is downvoted?

Comment: @Omer123 It's probably because such questions have to be asked on https://opensource.stackexchange.com and not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please note that this is not a legal advice.)
When you go to the [license site](https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker/blob/master/LICENSE) of the repository you can see the license is **Apache License 2.0**. You can see a long license text which describes what you may do or not.

There is also this explanation by github on the same page (the information is based on the license text):
[image]

I think you can use it in a commercial project but you have to add attribution. So you have to create an area in you app where you say that you are using this library. You also have to provide a link to the git repository and a copy of the license. But it's quite easy to do all that.

<s>Also note that when you modify the library you have to publish the source code.</s>
Also note that when modifying the source code you do not have to share it as [Apache 2 is not a copyleft license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-use-a-apache-v2-licensed-driver-for-a-commercial-project-without-revealing).

I recommand that you open Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox to see how they did it. In Chrome the URL is **chrome://credits** and on Firefox **about:license**.

Please also note that when you use a GPL licensed library for example you have to publish the source code of your whole app. But this is not the case for this Apache 2 licensed library as you can read [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/combining-apache-2-0-with-closed-source).

If a software has **public domain** as license you don't have to give attribution. [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) is in the public domain for example.

Almost all apps have an attribution menu. For example in the Android Google Chrome browser go to Settings > About Google Chrome > Legal information > Open-source licenses.

Comment: So you mean that I cannot use this library without contribution? What happen if I use this library without contribution?

Comment: No you cannot use this library without contribution. It depends on the country you are living it but it's probably illegal. Also someone could request to remove your app from the Play Store. I don't know why contribution is a problem? It's really only a small notice hidden somewhere in your "about menu".

Comment: Could you name an app that have done that? I want to see what it looks like... and second answer is which type of license doesn' require attribution? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Omer123 Sorry, it's called attribution not contribution. Almost all apps have this. See my edit on how to view it in Android Google Chrome.

Comment: Where to publish the source code after editing the library,  to my Repo or the library owner repo? Is it obligatory to publish library after edition to the github if I attribute the library in my app?

Comment: @Omer123 I was wrong, when modifying Apache 2 licensed software you do not need to share the source code. I edited my post and you can read it here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-use-a-apache-v2-licensed-driver-for-a-commercial-project-without-revealing But there are licenses which require it and then you have to release it to your own repository or provide a zip file hosted on your homepage.

Comment: But attribution still is obligatory for Apache 2.0 or MIT? If i change the library how do they know if I used their library? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Omer123 You have to list all Apache2/MIT libraries you are using so the user can see it. You also have to provide a copy of the license text. Someone could analayze your apk file and see which libs you are using. Maybe no-one would care if your app doesn't have many users but if you have a big company such things are important.

Comment: Appreciate your answer and comments thanks again.